# innodb_page_size cause problem row size too large

Tags: mysql, mariadb

The default value of `innodb_page_size` is 16K. After reading some tips about improving innodb i/o, I changed the value `innodb_page_size=4K`

But after that, I'm unable to import the SQL database file I just exported before the tweak and got the following error

```
ERROR 1118 (42000) at line 4769: Row size too large (> 1982). Changing some columns to TEXT or BLOB may help. In current row format, BLOB prefix of 0 bytes is stored inline
```

Any idea how to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The maximum row size is limited to about half of a page size, hence the error you got.

Switching to 4KB page size *may* be beneficial to a table with these characteristics:

- Mostly *random* accesses, AND
- The table is bigger than will fit in the buffer_pool (cf `innodb_buffer_pool_size`), AND
- The disk is HDD (as opposed to SSD, which tends to be fast enough to mask the improvement, AND
- The rows are small enough (as you already found), AND
- All *other* tables have small enough rows to fit.

Would you care to say where you got the advice?

Would you care to share the query/queries that have I/O performance issues.  Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` and `EXPLAIN ...`  There may be some simple ways to cut back on I/O, thereby avoiding the rather drastic step you took.

Comment: Thanks for the tips. I actually use SSD. I think that it's not a good deal to configure this globally because I can't ensure that all the rows are smalls. When you say "small enough", how to check the current row size of a table?

Comment: @ThanhTrung - "row size" is too complex for a Comment here.  Start a new Question with a couple of example schemas.  Point me at it and I (or someone else) will go into details.